# Jenkinsfile docker agent step dies after 1 second

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a very simple Jenkinsfile as seen below.

```
def workspace
node {
    workspace = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'pwd').trim()
}

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Back-end') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'composer'
                    args "-v /var/lib/jenkins/.composer/auth.json:/.composer/auth.json -v $workspace:/app"
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'php -v'
                sh 'composer install --no-interaction --working-dir=$WORKSPACE/backend'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've gotten to the point where this works entirely as intended (e.g.: mounts volumes as expected, moves things around, pulls image, actually runs `composer install`), with one minor exception...

The immediately following the `docker run` it gets into the shell steps, runs `sh 'composer install...'` and dies after 1 second, going into the `docker stop --time 1 ...` and `docker rm ...` steps immediately after.

I have no idea if this is coming from Composer doing something odd, or if there's some configurable timeout I'm completely unaware of.

Has anyone dealt with this before?

Edit:

Here is more information:

```
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 997:995 -v /var/lib/jenkins/.composer/auth.json:/.composer/auth.json -v [...] -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** --entrypoint cat composer
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[workspace] Running shell script
+ php -v
PHP 7.1.9 (cli) (built: Sep 15 2017 00:07:01) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
[Pipeline] sh
[workspace] Running shell script
+ composer install --no-interaction --working-dir=/app/backend --no-progress --no-ansi
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 29 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing laravel/tinker (v1.0.2): Downloading[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 ee693aaa7cdde41b714fdc91dbc1b05ac07fe2be7904ab1ed528fb0a3f771047
$ docker rm -f ee693aaa7cdde41b714fdc91dbc1b05ac07fe2be7904ab1ed528fb0a3f771047
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
```

and from an earlier job

```
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 55 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/finder (v3.3.6): Downloading (connecting...)[Pipeline] }
```

It's working as can be seen, but the return code at the end is....

```
GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

ERROR: script returned exit code -1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Edit 2:

Got this to work even simpler, see gist for more info:

https://gist.github.com/chuckyz/6b78b19a6a5ea418afa16cc58020096e

Comment: Is your jenkins running in a container itself?  Did the you look at the console output of the job?  Was there anything in their indicating an error?

Comment: See my edit above, hopefully someone has ran into this before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in Jenkins, so until this is marked as fixed I'm just using sh steps with `docker run ...` in them, manually.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35370

e.g.:

`sh 'docker run -v $WORKSPACE:/app composer install'`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this and resolved it by upgrading [durable-task-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Durable+Task+Plugin) from 1.13 to 1.16.

The 1.16 changelog contains:

> Using a new system for determining whether sh step processes are still alive, which should solve various robustness issues.